Graph theory exericse (path and cycle)
Recently I started learning graph theory. To get familiar with the vocabulary and definition I am trying to do some exercises.
Exercise:

Let $G(V,E)$ be a simple (finite) graph such that for all $v \in
V(G)$: $deg(v)\leq 2$.
Show that every connected component of $G(V,E)$ is either a cycle or a
path.

Approach:
I am not sure on how to tackle this exercise. Here is what I know:
I know that a path is a walk $(v_0,...,v_n)$ in which all vertices and edges are distinct.
A cycle is a walk $(v_0,...,v_n)$ where all edges and all vertices are distinct, except for $v_0=v_n$.
We used to defined connected components of a graph as the equivalence classes of the relation $~$, where $v_i ~ v_j$ if there exists a walk from $v_i$ to $v_j$.
For a set $A$ and a equivalence relation $~$, the equivalence classes are defined as the sets:
$[v]_{~}:=\{a \in A: a~v\}$.
Now the actuall approach:
Let $G_1(V_1,E_1)$ be a connected component of $G(V,E)$ such that $deg(v)\leq 2$ for every $v \in V_1$.
Since $G(V,E)$ is a simple graph, i.e. $E(G) \subseteq \binom{V(G)}{2}$, so is $G_1(V_1,E_1)$ a simple graph.
Thus for every $e \in E_1$, $|e|=2$.
If $deg(v)=2$, then $G_1$ is a closed walk.
If $deg(v) \leq 2$, then there exist $v_j$ such that $v_j=1$. In that case there has to be  $i \neq j$, $v_i$ such that $deg(v_i)=1$. Thus since $v_i,v_j \in G_1$ there exists a walk between $v_i$ and $v_j$ by definition of $G_1$.
How do I show that the closed walk in case $deg(v)=2$ is a cycle and the walk in the case $dev(v)\leq 2$ is a path?
(As I said at the beginning I am new to graph theory and I do not know how to formulate a "proper" proof. I would be happy if someone could also give me some feedback on the formalities of my approach. Since a lot of things are rather visual I am struggling on that part.)

Can you prove there is  a bijection $f$ with domain $X$ such that $E(G)={{v,f(v)}:v\in X}$ iff $\Delta(G)\leq 2$?

For example if all vertices have degree two then $f$ is a permutation i.e. a union/composition of cycles.

@EthanSplaver No, not really. How would one that this prove?
